# Search and subset list of lists

Tags: r

I have searched SO but could not find relevant answer.

Sample data:

```
example.list <- list(list("a",list("b"),list("c")),list("c"))
```

I would like to subset list that contains letter "c" :

Here this gets the last index node which contains letter "c":

```
check.a <- lapply(example.list, function(x) grep("c",x))
```

How I'm going to get the list with the above index? Or how to otherwise get the list of list?

A part of getting the last nodes of list c(1,3) there are preceding list nodes c(1,2).

EDIT: Desired output: (something like this)

```
 [[1]][[3]]
 [[1]][[3]][[1]]
 [1] "c"


 [[2]]
 [[2]][[1]]
 [1] "c"
```

However what I need is also to understand with that provided indexing, how can I get the subset of nested list? Please use `check.a`.

EDIT 2:

So here are the list indexes that could be used to subset the relevant list nodes:

```
first.list.index <- which(lapply(lapply(example.list, function(x) grep("c",x)),length)>0)
last.list.index <- unlist(lapply(example.list, function(x) grep("c",x)))
```

The idea is this: (not working, just to demonstrate what I'm after)

```
lapply(list(a=first.list.index,b=last.list.index), function(a,b) example.list[[a]][[b]])
```

EDIT 3: (LAST EDIT)

The actual data looks like this: (I hoped for solution with the indexing I provided, this is why I reduced the question on that)

```
 [[1]]
 [[1]][[1]]
 [1] "a"

 [[1]][[1]]$data

 [[1]][[2]]
 [[1]][[2]][[1]]
 [1] "b"

 [[1]][[1]]$data

 [[1]][[3]]
 [[1]][[3]][[1]]
 [1] "c"

 [[1]][[1]]$data


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1] "c"

[[2]][[1]]$data
```

Sorry for this mess!

Here is reduced dput:

```
     list(list(structure(list(name = "a", data = c("21016954")), .Names = c("name", "data"
     )), structure(list(name = "b", data = c("17103795")), .Names = c("name", "data")), structure(list(name = "c", 
     data = c("38036543")), .Names = c("name", "data"))),   list(structure(list(name = "c", data = c("42456597")), .Names =   c("name","data"))))
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: Try  `rapply(example.list, function(x) grep("c",x, value=TRUE))`

Comment: Hmmm... I just wrote a cool function to match your previous desired output. Bummer...

Comment: One option is `lapply(example.list, function(x) {x1 <- unlist(x); indx <- x1=='c'; relist(x1[indx], skeleton=x[indx])})` but the `[3]` part will be lost here.  I don't know if we can filter with that info unless we rename the list elements

Comment: Anyway, with your previous desired output, you could try `RecFunc <- function(x) {
  if(is.list(x)) {
    x <- unlist(x)
    RecFunc(x) 
  } else grep("c", x, value = TRUE)
} ; lapply(example.list, RecFunc)`

Comment: There must be some clash between the structures.  BTW, why do you need it to remain in the nested form?

Comment: That's called a recursive function.

Comment: Can you try by `example.list <- as.relistable(example.list)`

Comment: Yes... you need a `;` after `x <- unlist(x)`... That what happens when posting stuff in comments :)

Comment: Is it the same example.list?

Comment: Can you make necessary change in the example.list as it is not easy to construct it from the output showed

Comment: You can use `dput` and get the output from a subset of your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second edit is along the right lines, but you need to use `Map` instead of `lapply`. Using your data

```
d <-  list(list(structure(list(name = "a", data = c("21016954")), .Names = c("name", "data"
    )), structure(list(name = "b", data = c("17103795")), .Names = c("name", "data")), structure(list(name = "c", 
    data = c("38036543")), .Names = c("name", "data"))),   list(structure(list(name = "c", data = c("42456597")), .Names =   c("name","data"))))

Map(function(i, j) d[[i]][[j]], 
    i = which(lapply(lapply(d, function(x) grep("c",x)),length)>0), 
    j = unlist(lapply(d, function(x) grep("c",x))))

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$name
#[1] "c"
#
#[[1]]$data
#[1] "38036543"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$name
#[1] "c"
#
#[[2]]$data
#[1] "42456597"
```

Comment: yes, yes indeed! Function `Map` I was after! Thanks a lot!